# Would one expect these definitions of mass densities to coincide in FLRW metric?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, cosmology, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

### Background

Let's say we are in the FLRW metric. We define $n^\mu$ as the time-like vector which is orthogonal to all the spacelike Killing vectors. To gain the momentum density we perform the contraction
$$ P^{\mu} = T^{\mu \nu} n_\nu.$$

Now to define mass density $m$ we do something similar to [Komar mass](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.5429) (page 3) (with the exception we have used the normal vector instead of killing vectors),
$$ - m^2 = P^\mu P_{\mu}.$$

### Question

Does this definition of mass density compare to the "naïve" mass density one would gain from this [analysis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/680091/150174) (in the low energy limit? What about the high energy limit?). I believe the linked answer only works on the low energy limit.

Comment: That naive mass density is only the averaged mass density in weak field limit. Have you checked your calculation for $M[D]$ in the weak field limit by choosing $n^{\mu}=(1, 0,0,0) $ , so that $\sqrt{\gamma}\approx 1$?

Comment: @KP99 there is annoying pre-factor of $n^{\mu} u_{\mu}$ in front of my mass density. (Assuming my calculations are correct)

Comment: Wait. Isn't vector field $n$ same as the vector field $u$? The attached article uses $n$ to denote the unit normal vector, which is again the velocity of the fluids. So $n^{\mu}u_{\mu}=n^{\mu}n_{\mu}=-1$. Simple :)

Comment: I don't think $n^\mu = u^\mu$. I defined $n^\mu$ as: 
"We define $n^\mu$ as the time-like vector which is orthogonal to all the spacelike Killing vectors"

Comment: But maybe $P^\mu = T^{\mu \nu} u_{\nu}$ is a more natural definition?

Comment: In page no. 3 of the attached article, the $n^{\mu}$ vector is defined to be 
 time-like orthogonal to space-like hypersurface $\Sigma_t$. In 3+1 formalism, if we consider a non-tilted fluid $T_{ab}$, then $n^{\mu}$ has the natural interpretation of being the fluid velocity ($u^{\mu}$). Here, we have to assume $n^{\mu}=u^{\mu}$ in order to interpret $P^{\mu}$ as momentum density. Consider for flat space-time, a static observer has $n=(1,0,0,0)$, then $-T^{\mu\nu}n_{\mu}=T^{0\mu}=P^{\mu}$

Comment: Thanks!! Makes sense :)